FreeBSD install using shell and partition by hand
I'm trying to install FreeBSD 14 using ZFS, but I do not want to use the full disk so I am using the Shell option. I was following these instructions.
A. Boot FreeBSD install DVD or USB Memstick
B. Select Install, and answer questions such as keyboard layout and hostname
C. When prompted to partition the disk:
  i. If you do not want to use the entire disk, skip to the Partition Creation section
  ii. choose the 'shell' option
  iii. Determine which disk you wish to use: camcontrol devlist
  iv. Create a fresh partition table: gpart destroy ada0

Step C.4 is where the issue lies. I get to the Partitioning section of the install and choose Shell. I use camcontrol devlist to see my devices and then run gpart destroy nda0 which returns an error Device busy.
# gpart destroy nda0
gpart: Device busy

I tried running the gpart destroy nda0 command without running the camcontrol devlist command in case it did something and also tried rebooting and running the installer fresh with no success.
Does this mean the device is mounted? That's a bit strange to me and doesn't seem to be the case when I check df:
df
Filesystem                   Mounted On
/dev/ufs/FreeBSD_Install     /
devfs                        /dev
tmpfs                        /tmp
tmpfs                        /var

Next guess would be an issue with the drivers for the drive? Some searching I seen this which references adding the following to the loader.conf:
nvme_load="YES"
nvd_load="YES"

I'm not sure how to do that though when running from a USB. Is there anyway to load the proper drivers once I enter the Shell?

I found the issue. From the gpart manual:
   Deleting Partitions and Destroying the Partitioning Scheme
       If  a Device busy error is shown when trying to destroy a partition ta-
       ble, remember that all of the partitions must be deleted first with the
       delete action.  In this example, da0 has three partitions:

         /sbin/gpart delete -i 3 da0
         /sbin/gpart delete -i 2 da0
         /sbin/gpart delete -i 1 da0
         /sbin/gpart destroy da0

       Rather than deleting each partition and then destroying the  partition-
       ing  scheme,  the  -F option can be given with destroy to delete all of
       the partitions before destroying  the  partitioning  scheme.   This  is
       equivalent to the previous example:

         /sbin/gpart destroy -F da0

I was misled by the message. I've only ever seen Device Busy mean that a device is mounted or being used. Even searching led me down that road. It was this old bug which pointed me in the right direction.
If this should be deleted feel free, but posting the solution here in case it helps anyone else.
